# Swarming in AS2

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

Hi I keep getting the error: expecting identifier before greater than.
on line 13.
Any help would be nice please and Thank you.

```
    fly = function () {
    this.animate = function() {
        // Capture mouse positions and distance from mouse
        this.targetX = _root._xmouse;
        this.targetY = _root._ymouse;
        this.distX = this.targetX-this.meX+this.flockX;
        this.distY = this.targetY-this.meY+this.flockY;
        // 
        if ((this.targetX == this.oldTargetX) && Math.random()>0.9) {
            // add small scale random darting if mouse is still
            this.flockX = (Math.random()*100)-50;
            this.flockY = (Math.random()*100)-50;
        } else if ((this.targetX<>this.oldTargetX) && Math.random()>0.8) {
            // add large scale random darting if mouse is moving
            this.flockX = (Math.random()*400)-200;
            this.flockY = (Math.random()*400)-200;
        }
        // Apply inertia equation
        this.meX = Math.round(this.meX+(this.distX)/20);
        this.meY = Math.round(this.meY+(this.distY)/20);
        // perform animation
        this._x = this.meX;
        this._y = this.meY;
        // remember the current mouse pos so we can tell if
        // it has moved next time around
        this.oldTargetX = this.targetX;
    };
    this.initialize = function() {
        this.targetX = 0;
        this.targetY = 0;
        this.distX = 0;
        this.distY = 0;
        this.meX = this._x;
        this.meY = this._y;
        this.oldTargetX = 0;
        this.flockX = (Math.random()*200)-100;
        this.flockY = (Math.random()*200)-100;
    };
    // set up onEnterFrame script to animate _parent...
    this.initialize();
    this.onEnterFrame = this.animate;
};
    //
    //
    var i:Number = 0;
    var bugClip:MovieClip;
    for (i=0; i<30; i++) {
        bugClip = this.attachMovie("bug", "bug"+i, i);
        fly.apply(bugClip);
    }
```

Comment: you need to edit your code in a code block, otherwise no one will answer your question

Comment: @StudentRik I've modified your question (use the {} symbol to format code on stackoverflow), your title said AS3, but the code is clearly AS2. I think the error might be caused by this: `this.targetX<>this.oldTargetX`. Is this a mistake (should it be < or > ) or do you mean 'different'/'not equal', in which case you should use the `!`(NOT) operator: `this.targetX != this.oldTargetX`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Actionscript, but by looking at your code I would recomend doing like this:

```
    randomValue = Math.random()
    if ((this.targetX == this.oldTargetX) && randomValue>0.9) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The <> operator for not equals has been deprecated since Flash Player 5 [Doc reference here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html)

You should use != for the same functionality.

Although i tested this on Flash Player 10.2 and it will still compile and run with no errors. I guess you are compiling to a later version.